# Using XML::Twig, how can I detect the last sibling?

Tags: perl, siblings, xml-twig, nextsibling

Using Perl XML::Twig, how can I loop on each sibling until reaching the last node ?

```
while (condition_sibling_TWIG, $v)
{
$v=$v->next_sibling;
$v->print;

# process $v 
}
```

Should the condition be ($v != undef) ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next_siblings` to get the list of siblings:

```
foreach my $sibling ($elt->next_siblings)
  { # process sibling
  }
```

`next_siblings` accepts an optional condition as argument, which is an XPath step, or at least the subset of XPath supported by XML::Twig: `$elt->next_siblings('p[@type="secret"]'))`

Comment: thank you it works perfectly. But how to do, if I want TWIG to continue in the next Element ( SOURCE id="USA" ) to look for next_siblings: `<main>
<SOURCE id="AFRICA">
    <DEST id="RUSSIA" method="delete"/>
    <DEST id="USA" method="modify"/>
</SOURCE>
<SOURCE id="USA">
    <DEST id="AUSTRALIA" method="modify"/>
    <DEST id="CANADA" method="create"/>
    
</SOURCE>
</main>  `

Comment: -> next_siblings makes me jump from DEST to DEST. But I can not access the second Element ("USA")

Comment: it looks like you need to navigate a 2-level structure, SOURCE and nested DEST. You probably need to use nested loops, the outer one on SOURCE elements, the inner one on DEST children. Or have a handler on SOURCE and a loop on DEST children (using the `children` method) within. I may be wrong, but it seems to me that the mental model you are using is not the right one: you need to navigate the XML as a tree, not as a linear flow of data. Use `children` and (maybe) `parent` instead of `next-sibling`

Comment: I will revise the algorithm and give you update upon my implementation

Comment: I am using both next_elt (move from SOURCE) and first_child (to step down one level)                                              `my $city="PARIS";
    $v= $v->next_elt(SOURCE[@id=\$city]');
    $v=$v->first_child;

 
    foreach my $v ($v ->next_siblings) 
    {
     print $v->start_tag;
     # process $v
    }`                                                                                                                                      But I face a problem to use the variable $city.   `next_elt(SOURCE[@id=\$city]')` does not understand $city. Any help ?

Comment: `v= $v->next_elt("city[\@id\=\"$tot\"]");` was the solution

Comment: As it is you don't process the first child, is that OK? If you need to process all of them you can replace the `first_child`/`siblungs` combo by just `children`. I would also use 2 different variables, with 2 names: one for sources and one for dests. Finally, you can also use perl flexible quoting system to avoid some backslashes: `$v->next_elt( qq{city[\@id="$tot"]})`

Comment: thank you. Yes I need to use `children`, else I have to insert two times my "process code" (`first_child`, then `next_siblings`). Amy chance you could copy/paste some sample code using `children` (I need the tags values, not the hashes) ?

Comment: You should not access directly the hashes, an element is an object, use methods to access it: `$elt->tag` for the tag name, `$elt->att( 'toto')` for the attribute 'toto'. Read the docs and the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

The `sibling` method returns the next sibling or undef if no siblings are left. You can use it to fetch the next one until there are none left.

> sibling ($offset, $optional_condition)
>
> ```
> Return the next or previous $offset-th sibling of the element, or the $offset-th one matching $optional_condition. If $offset is
> ```
>
> negative then a previous sibling is returned, if $offset is positive
>   then a next sibling is returned. $offset=0 returns the element if
>   there is no condition or if the element matches the condition>, undef
>   otherwise.

Here's an example:

```
use strict; use warnings; 
use XML::Twig;
my $t= XML::Twig->new();
$t->parse(<<__XML__
<root>
    <stuff>
        <entry1></entry1>
        <entry2></entry2>
        <entry3></entry3>
        <entry4></entry4>
        <entry5></entry5>
    </stuff>
</root>
__XML__
);
my $root = $t->root;
my $entry = $root->first_child('stuff')->first_child('entry1');
while ($entry = $entry->sibling(1)) {
  say $entry->print . ' (' . $entry->path . ')';
}
```

*This only gives you the ones that come after the element you already have. If you start at entry 3 you will only get entries 4 and 5.*

---

**Original (edited) answer:**

You can also use the `siblings` method to iterate over a list of all siblings of an element.

> siblings ($optional_condition)
>
> ```
> Return the list of siblings (optionally matching $optional_condition) of the element (excluding the element itself).
> ```
>
> The elements are ordered in document order.

Replace the code from above with this:

```
my $root = $t->root;
my $entry1 = $root->first_child('stuff')->first_child('entry1');
# This is going to give us entries 2 to 5
foreach my $sibling ($entry1->siblings) {
  say $sibling->print . ' (' . $sibling->path . ')';
}
```

*This gives you all siblings of your starting element, but not that one itself. If you start at `entry3` you will get entries 1, 2, 4 and 5.*

Comment: should I use:                                                      foreach my $sibling ($entry1->siblings) {say $sibling->print . ' (' . $sibling->path . ')';                                                                                                                                  **OR** while ($entry = $entry->sibling(1)) {
  say $entry->print . ' (' . $entry->path . ')';

Comment: You can pick the one you like, or even use `next_siblings` instead of `siblings` like @mirod proposed. It's up to you. But if you only want the siblings that come **after** the one you have in your document, the `while`-loop with `sibling(1)` or a `foreach`-loop with `next_siblings` are the way to go. I changed the answer accordingly.